# What does the notation ab1, ab2, etc. refer to in predicate logic?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, artificial-intelligence

I'm trying to decipher a set of relations from a [John McCarthy paper](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1624103):

$$
specializes(c1,c2) \land \neg ab1(p,c1,c2) \land ist(c1,p) \supset ist(c2,p)
$$

and

$$
specializes(c1,c2) \land \neg ab2(p,c1,c2) \land ist(c2,p) \supset ist(c1,p)
$$

The text is fairly clear about what the functions $specializes(\cdot)$ and $ist(\cdot)$ mean, but I have know idea what is meant by $ab1(\cdot)$ and $ab2(\cdot)$. Any ideas?

Comment: Computer Science paper that uses obscure notations without introducing them? What else is new? You may have better luck asking on http://cs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer in another paper by [Akman and Surav](http://scholar.google.fi/scholar_url?url=http://cogprints.org/460/2/cipaper.ps&hl=en&sa=X&scisig=AAGBfm0-Rpz_ajP0exEXBWLuLDDbkTLkqg&oi=scholarr&ei=woGuVMunE4LBPMHBgYgM&ved=0CB8QgAMoADAA):

> ab is an abnormality predicate to support non­-monotonicity.
>   $$
> \forall c_1 \forall c_2 \forall p (c_1 \preceq c_2) \land ist(c1,p) \land \neg ab(p,c1,c2)   \to ist(c2,p)
> $$

Abnormality predicates seem to come from [an earlier paper by McCarthy](http://www.google.fi/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCYQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fcogprints.org%2F415%2F2%2Fapplications.ps&ei=EYSuVM7KCcfUOo7QgbAE&usg=AFQjCNHjUnhh7anBEAaw9B9e5degLQODzA&sig2=9FHTPIycY5jg1BiAXX4x9g&bvm=bv.83134100,d.ZWU&cad=rja):

> A single predicate *ab*, standing for ``abnormal'' is circumscribed 
>   with certain other predicates and functions considered as variables that can 
>   be constrained to achieve the circumscription subject to the axioms.

I think McCarthy often assumes you've read all his earlier papers, and therefore you can understand his notation...

Comment: ... and/or that the referees wouldn't dare or care to bug him about such things.